# How can I increase the precision of the result of RegionPlot for this function?

Tags: plotting, functions

I have this function

```
f := 1024 (1 - (9 x^2)/4)^2 Cosh[(π x)/
    3]^2 Sinh[π x]^2 (8 (16 - 216 x^2 + 
        81 x^4 + (4 + 9 x^2)^2 Cosh[(2 π x)/3]) Sinh[π x]^2 - 
     1/256 ((4 + 9 x^2)^2 Sinh[x (2 π - y)] + 
        2 (64 - 144 x^2 + (4 + 9 x^2)^2 Cosh[(2 π x)/3]) Sinh[
          x y] - 9 (4 - 3 x^2)^2 Sinh[x (2 π + y)])^2);
```

I want to see in what range of variables, this function is negative. Using RegionPlot

```
RegionPlot[ f < 0, {y, 2, 2.25}, {x, 1.15, 1.17}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 30, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

I obtain this plot

[image]

Then, when I diminish the ranges as

```
RegionPlot[ 
 f < 0, {y, Rationalize[2.1299849, 0], Rationalize[2.1299855, 0]}, {x,
   Rationalize[1.15970110, 0], Rationalize[1.15970113, 0]}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 90, PlotPoints -> 150]
```

I obtain

[image]

Here, it is not clear if the blue parts touch or not. How can I go more into detail to see whether the blue part is continuous or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Simplest plotting solution*

```
ContourPlot[f,
 {y, Rationalize[2.1299849, 0],  Rationalize[2.1299855, 0]},
 {x, Rationalize[1.15970110, 0], Rationalize[1.15970113, 0]},
 ContourShading ->
  {RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798, 0.4], None},
 Contours -> {{0}},
 PlotPoints -> 25, WorkingPrecision -> 32,
 Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}
 ]
```

> [image]

But plots are not always very convincing, being designed to give only a rough idea of what is going on.

*Analytic solution*

As I showed in [this answer to a similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228612/how-can-i-have-an-accurate-plot-to-make-sure-that-this-plot-is-continuous-or-not/228615#228615), we can analytically show there's a node:

```
jac = D[f, {{x, y}}];
cpsol = FindRoot[jac == {0, 0}, {{x, 1.15}, {y, 2.13}}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 50];
cpt = {x, y} /. cpsol
f /. cpsol      (* shows cpt is on curve *)
f /. N[cpsol]   (* show numerical noise at cpt is substantial *)
```

> ```
> (*
>   {1.1597011139328870007473930523093558428367204499142, 
>    2.1299852028277681162523681416937176426970454505325}
>   0.*10^-36
>   0.0119859
> *)
> ```

*Taming `RegionPlot`*

`RegionPlot` has been evolving since the introduction of `Region` functionality.  `RegionPlot` seems to use this functionality to generate the plot, and it ignores the `WorkingPrecision` option, which is evident from the numerical noise.  I believe the region functionality is based on the FEM functionality, which is available only in machine precision.  (Similarly, the option `MaxRecursion` seems defunct.)

Here is a way to sieze control of the working precision:

```
ClearAll[fff];
fff[x0_Real, y0_Real] := 
  Block[{x = SetPrecision[x0, Infinity], 
    y = SetPrecision[y0, Infinity]},
   N[
    1024 (1 - (9 x^2)/4)^2 Cosh[(π x)/
        3]^2 Sinh[π x]^2 (8 (16 - 216 x^2 + 
          81 x^4 + (4 + 9 x^2)^2 Cosh[(2 π x)/
             3]) Sinh[π x]^2 - 
       1/256 ((4 + 9 x^2)^2 Sinh[x (2 π - y)] + 
           2 (64 - 144 x^2 + (4 + 9 x^2)^2 Cosh[(2 π x)/3]) Sinh[
             x y] - 9 (4 - 3 x^2)^2 Sinh[x (2 π + y)])^2),
    $MachinePrecision]
   ];

RegionPlot[
 fff[x, y] < 0,
 {y, Rationalize[2.1299849, 0],  Rationalize[2.1299855, 0]},
 {x, Rationalize[1.15970110, 0], Rationalize[1.15970113, 0]},
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

> [image]

But one swallow does not a summer make.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have another question. When we put the obtained roots in the equation, then, the result must essentially be zero times a negative power of ten? OR if gives a positive number times a negative power of ten, it is also verified that there exist a root?

Comment: The result ``0.*10^-36`` is a zero calculated with arbitrary-precision numbers. It represents a quantity $y$ such that $|y| < 10^{-36}$.  So there is some uncertainty in the result but it is very small.  You can increase the `WorkingPrecision` by 100 and the uncertainty will decrease to $10^{-136}$, exactly one orders of magnitude less, evidence that we found a zero. There is always uncertainty when using approximate numbers, so it cannot be proved to be zero by such means (proved in a mathematical sense)....

Comment: @Sasha1988 ...OTOH, if the result obtained with arbitrary precision is nonzero, it means that the result is very probably nonzero.  If you double the `WorkingPrecision` and the result is the same, it almost certainly is not zero (again, there is always uncertainty with numerical methods). When an arbitrary-precision number is displayed as nonzero, it means the uncertainty due to round-off error is less than the magnitude of the number. HTH

Answer (score 2):

Since you are interested in whether the two regions meet, you can also use `ContourPlot`, which appears to be a bit more stable:

```
ContourPlot[f == 0, {y, 2.1299849, 2.1299855}, {x, 1.15970110, 1.15970113}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 40, MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

[image]